# Kolmogorov zero-one law for lim sup

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be a sequence of independent random variables and {$b_n$} a sequence such that $0 \leq b_n \uparrow \infty$, $S_n = \sum_1^nX_i$. How can I show

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{S_n}{b_n}\right) = \mbox{constant}\right) = 1?$$

I have two questions:

- I think it is done with an application of Kolmogorov's 0-1 law, but how to show that $\left[\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{S_n}{b_n}\right) \leq c\right]$ is a tail-event, if it is? I think this would be enough to conclude that $F_{\limsup S_n/b_n}(c)$ is 0 or 1 for each $c$ and, therefore, it would be either a finite constant, $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ a.s., Hence why I want to know if infinity counts as constant.
- In this context, does the word "constant" include $+\infty$ or $-\infty$? I mean, if I assume constant cannot be an infinite value, does the conclusion change? I took this question from a past year's exam, so I'm not sure what was agreed here.

These questions came up because I thought of the following example:

- (a) $X_n = n²$ a.s. and $b_n = n$, what makes $\limsup \left( \frac{S_n}{b_n} \right) = +\infty$. If there is nothing wrong with this example and the result holds, then I think the definition of constant includes $+\infty$.

Comment: Kolmogorov 0/1 requires variables to be independent.  Also, there is a "0" in the "0/1" law, meaning that the probability of a tail event is either 0 or 1 (we cannot conclude it is always 1).

Comment: Your example of deterministic $X_n=n^2$ indeed satisfies the "independence" needed for Kolmogorov, and indeed shows the limit can be $\infty$, which is usually not viewed as being a "constant."  If the problem really just wants you to show the limsup is always the same (possibly infinite) value with prob 1, it should more clearly communicate that.  Without independence you could construct an example of a fair coin flip: If heads we have $X_n=0$ for all $n$; if tails we have $X_n=n^2$ for all $n$. So the $\limsup$ can take either $\infty$ or $0$, with equal probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all (as pointed out in the comments above), you need to put some assumptions on the sequence $X_n$, such as **independence** for example. Since otherwise, just taking $X_n = X_1$ for all $n$ and $b_n = n$, we do not get the claim unless $X_1$ is deterministic.

So, henceforth I will assume that we're dealing with **independent** sequence of random variables.

Next, you are right that $\pm \infty$ should be treated as a constant. Indeed, assume $X_1$ is integrable with expectation $\mu$, so that we get the strong law of large numbers (SLLN).
Then, 
$$
(*) \lim \frac{S_n}{b_n} = \lim \frac{S_n}{n} \frac{n}{b_n}.
$$
Now, $S_n/n$ converges a.s. to $\mu$, and if you take $b_n$ so that $n/b_n \to \infty$, then (*) converges to infinity a.s.

Finally, your guess on Kolmogorov's 0-1 is also correct (observe that we need the i.i.d assumption now), as for any constant $c $ (including infinities) the event

$$
E_{c} = \left\{\limsup \frac{S_n}{b_n} \leq c \right\}
$$
is clearly a tail event in view of the fact that $b_n \to \infty$. Hence by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law we have that the distribution function
$$
F(c) =  \mathbb{P} (  \limsup \frac{S_n}{b_n} \leq c )
$$
is either 0 or 1. But $F$ is non-decreasing and $F(+\infty) = 1$ and hence for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$ it has to become 1 unless $F(-\infty) = 1$. Now, taking $c_* = \sup \{ c \in \mathbb{R}: F(c) = 0 \} $ gives us the constant for which
$$
\mathbb{P} (  \limsup \frac{S_n}{b_n} =c_* ) = 1 .
$$

Comment: In fact, I forgot to write the assumption that they were independent (just edited the question now), but I think your answer just requires the variables to be independent, not i.i.d. right?

Comment: yes, you're right, we only need independence for Kolmogorov's 0-1 , i.i.d is superfluous, I'll edit the answer, thanks.